# Upload a file from web to a server in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I have a php code which uploads my photos to a server. The code works fine for local files, but it is not working for files from Web. Below is my code for uploading local files

```
<?php

    $filepath="@/home/path/to/my/file.png";
    $serverurl ="https://cxdetails.com/upload.php";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $serverurl);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    $post=array("file"=>$filepath);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;

?>
```

but it is not working if I change the $filepath to "http://www.howtocheck.zu/path/sarah.png". Am not sure why this is not working. Please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure if curl support "downloading" from web before upload file to https://cxdetails.com/upload.php.

Comment: I am not sure about curl downloading, is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can u try replace:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($post));
```

Comment: Why would this help, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can take an array parameter

Comment: That didn't help @Dmitry. I am just confused on what is the difference here and why it is not taking the file from web? Am I missing something?

Comment: By adding http_build_query CURL sets header "Content-type: multipart/form-data". Also, you can try to add this header manually like: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));